# Why is worst case of is_permutation O(n^2)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, permutation

The C++ docs say that the worst case time complexity for [is_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_permutation) is O(N^2):

> At most O(N^2) applications of the predicate, or exactly N if the sequences are already equal, where N=std::distance(first1, last1).  However if ForwardIt1 and ForwardIt2 meet the requirements of LegacyRandomAccessIterator and std::distance(first1, last1) != std::distance(first2, last2) no applications of the predicate are made.

However, IMO it should be O(NlogN) in the worst case - can we not just sort both the sequences in [O(NlogN)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and then just compare them?  What am I missing?

Comment: *Elements are compared using operator==* : the type behind does not necessary have the operator `<` defined.

Comment: If you sorted, then you'd modify the data, which could be bad.  It's also possible that the data set can't be sorted.

Comment: @molbdnilo I don't think copyability of the elements is a requirement. The indices of the elements could be used as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`is_permutation` doesn't require the ranges to be sortable. It only uses the `bool`-valued comparison predicate.

Furthermore, the ranges are immutable, so even if they could be sorted, the sorting would imply creation of an index on one of the ranges. That would add `O(N)` memory cost to the `O(NlogN)` cost of index generation.